# No output in program?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2013, playing-cards

I am making a program to shuffle a deck of cards and deal out two hands, but right now, there is no output!  I combed through the code for infinite loops, but I can't find anything!  Can someone please help me?

```
// (Description in Word File)
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

unsigned seed = time(0); // for use of rand()

const int SUIT = 4;
const int FACE = 13;
const int HAND = 5;

// A couple of reference arrays.
const string SUITS[SUIT] = {" Hearts", " Diamonds", " Clubs", " Spades"};
const string FACES[FACE] = {"Ace of", "Two of", "Three of",
                            "Four of", "Five of", "Six of", "Seven of",
                            "Eight of", "Nine of", "Ten of",
                            "Jack of", "Queen of", "King of"};

// The reason that these functions are in Main is because
// it gives me error 2065: undeclared identifier otherwise.
void shuffle(string[][FACE]);
void deal(string[][FACE], string[HAND]);
void displayDeck(string[][FACE]);
void displayHand(string[HAND]);

int main()
{
    string deck[SUIT][FACE];
    string hand1[HAND];
    string hand2[HAND];

    srand(seed); // for use of rand()

    // Shuffle the deck.
    shuffle(deck);

        // Now display the deck
    displayDeck(deck);

    // Deal for each hand.
    deal(deck, hand1);
    deal(deck, hand2);

    // Now display each hand.
    displayHand(hand1);
    displayHand(hand2);

    return 0;
}

// This function will keep track of face values
// for the shuffle function
bool duplCheck(string cards[][FACE], int suit, int face)
{
    bool status = true;
    for (int count1 = 0; count1 != SUIT; count1++)
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 != FACE; count2++)
            if (cards[count1][count2] == cards[suit][face]
                && suit != count1 && face != count2)
                return false;
    return status;
}

// This function will shuffle the deck.
void shuffle(string cards[][FACE])
{
    int randFace, randSuit;
    // These loops will assign random face values
    // and suits to each place in cards[][].
    for (int count1 = 0; count1 != SUIT; count1++)
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 != FACE; count2++)  
        {
            do
            {
                randFace = rand() % FACE;
                randSuit = rand() % SUIT;
                if (duplCheck(cards, randSuit, randFace) == true)
                    cards[count1][count2] = 
                        FACES[randFace] + SUITS[randSuit];
            } while(duplCheck(cards, randSuit, randFace) == false);
        }
}

// This function deals out a hand of five random cards.
void deal(string cards[][FACE], string hand[HAND])
{
    for (int count = 0; count != HAND; count++)
    {
        // make random suit and face numbers
        int randSuit = rand() % SUIT;
        int randFace = rand() % FACE;

        // If random card is not obsolete...
        if (cards[randSuit][randFace] != "null")
            // ...assign that card to hand.
            hand[count] = cards[randSuit][randFace];

        // obsolete that card
        cards[randSuit][randFace] = "null";
    }
}

void displayDeck(string cards[][FACE])
{
    std::cout << "\t\tThe Deck:\n\n";
    for (int count1 = 0; count1 != SUIT; count1++)
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 != FACE; count2++)
        {
            std::cout << ((count1 * FACE) + count2 + 1) << " "
                << cards[count1][count2] << endl;
        }
}

void displayHand(string hand[HAND])
{

}
```

Comment: `displayHand` does nothing. 

What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What does "duplCheck" do that you call it twice inside shuffle's main loop? 30 seconds adding some extra output shows this is where your code breaks. http://ideone.com/BkZKD9

Comment: As far as I can tell you never get out of `shuffle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in shuffle, specifically in the use of duplCheck.

```
void shuffle(string cards[][FACE])
{
    int randFace, randSuit;
    // These loops will assign random face values
    // and suits to each place in cards[][].
    for (int count1 = 0; count1 != SUIT; count1++)
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 != FACE; count2++)  
        {
            do
            {
                randFace = rand() % FACE;
                randSuit = rand() % SUIT;
                std::cout << count1 << "," << count2 << " trying " << randFace << "/" << randSuit << std::endl;
                if (duplCheck(cards, randSuit, randFace) == true) {
                    std::cout << "duplCheck returned true" << std::endl;
                    cards[count1][count2] = 
                        FACES[randFace] + SUITS[randSuit];
                }
            } while(duplCheck(cards, randSuit, randFace) == false);
        }
}
```

I've added some extra output. This demonstrates (http://ideone.com/BkZKD9) that duplCheck isn't returning false the first time you run it.

```
do
{
    randFace = rand() % FACE;
    randSuit = rand() % SUIT;
    if (duplCheck(cards, randSuit, randFace) == true) {
               ... this doesn't happen
    }
} while(duplCheck(cards, randSuit, randFace) == false);
```

Because duplCheck returns false, you stay permanently in this loop.

```
bool duplCheck(string cards[][FACE], int suit, int face)
{
    bool status = true;
    for (int count1 = 0; count1 != SUIT; count1++)
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 != FACE; count2++)
            if (cards[count1][count2] == cards[suit][face]
                && suit != count1 && face != count2)
                return false;
    return status;
}
```

It appears that duplCheck returns "false" if there is a duplicate and "true" if there isn't, but your use of it expects the opposite: your while loop stops when duplCheck returns true, it expects duplCheck to return true if there IS a duplicate.

Comment: It didn't work, no matter what I changed.  I guess I'll take a different approach.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out another way.  Boy, was this project a pain!!

Answer (score 0):

Your display hand function is empty.

```
void displayHand(string hand[HAND])
{
    cout << "Put some output here";
}
```

Comment: Valid but not the answer.

Comment: I wanted to add it as a comment but I don't have enough reputation... @kfsone

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your deck initially starts out with empty ("") values. You can either fill this at the start, before calling shuffle(), or you can add this check to the start of duplCheck():

```
if(cards[suit][face].length() == 0)
   return true;
```